# Webkit blur fadeout on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit

```
$(window).load(function(){ $("#data").animate({-webkit-filter:blur(0px)}, 1500 ); });
```

(where #data is some part of the body, with width=100% and height=100%, and has some other layers on it) Please look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNjrY.png) image.

I want *that translucent part* (#data) to become clear after the loader (z-index higher than #data) goes away, i.e. on page load. But this code isn't working. Are there any alternatives? Also..I want that to be animated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using the jquery.fadeIn effect will give you what you are looking for?

```
$(window).load(function(){ $('#data').fadeIn(1500) });
```

[jQuery fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: http://harshalgajjar.tk/index_blur.html This is the link with the same code ..and this is how it should be after -webkit-filter:blur(0px) - http://www.harshalgajjar.tk/index.html